# Pycharm checking thousands of files during refactoring in a small project: why?

Tags: pycharm, refactoring, python-venv

Whenever I rename a variable or delete a file in my **Pycharm** project with "Safe delete (with usage search)" option it starts searching for usages among thousands of files.

[image]

Since my project is made of not more than 10 `.py` or `.html` files I am thinking it is probably looking also in the `venv` folder. If my guess is correct, how to exclude these files from the search?

Comment: Do you store your venv inside the project? Try right-clicking it in the project tree -> Mark directory as ... -> Excluded.

Comment: @PavelKarateev yes! I shouldn't? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @PavelKarateev I confirm you that your solution worked! If you make an answer out of it I will certainly mark it as correct :)

Comment: Done. There is nothing wrong with storing venvs inside projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you store the venv inside the project right-click it in the project tree -> Mark directory as -> Excluded.

Explanation: if the venv is not excluded PyCharm will treat it as a part of the project source code so the IDE will e.g. try to search venv files while attempting to refactor some object to update references to it.

PyCharm is smart enough to auto-exclude venvs in some cases but not always, unfortunately.

P.S.: Storing venvs inside projects is absolutely OK, though some people prefer a single location of `~/.virtualenvs`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Find Usage Dialog Box]You can choose the scope in `Find Usages Settings dialog` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>). It will then only include the files in the defined scope.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this combination of keys doesn't work for me (maybe we are using a different OS? I have Ubuntu 20.04). Anyway Alt+Shift+7 brings me to "Find Usages": from here I found "Settings" but I am not sure how to operate. Can you be more specific? Thanks again!

Comment: I have added picture of the dialog box. You need to select the desired scope there.